# Alter table max length in sql not working

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to alter my table `ADDRESS` for column `ADDRESS_TYPE` from `VARCHAR(10)` to `VARCHAR(50)`.

I tried

```
ALTER TABLE ADDRESS ALTER ADDRESS_TYPE VARCHAR(50);
ALTER TABLE ADDRESS MODIFY ADDRESS_TYPE VARCHAR(50);
ALTER TABLE ADDRESS ALTER COLUMN ADDRESS_TYPE VARCHAR(50);
ALTER TABLE ADDRESS CHANGE ADDRESS_TYPE VARCHAR(50);
```

none of them work and i got a DB2 SQL error:

> SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601.

This table is part of constraint in a few other tables. Trying to get the correct ALTER statement to modify the max length.

Comment: I've removed apparent superfluous database tags. Please only tag products in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `DB2`, your syntax should be

```
ALTER TABLE ADDRESS
      ALTER COLUMN ADDRESS_TYPE SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR(50)
```

Answer (score 0):

In DB2, syntaxes differ from SQL. Hope the below command will work for you:

```
ALTER TABLE ADDRESS ALTER COLUMN ADDRESS_TYPE SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR(50);
```